# Can't install kwin-common when trying to install KDE Plasma

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, kde

I cannot install `kwin-common` when trying to install KDE Plasma. I've tried `sudo apt update` and other Google answers, such as `dpkg -a --configure`, `apt upgrade`, but none of them worked.

Comment: Please add full output to the question - which commands you execute, which error messages you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by downloading an iso and installing it.